# android sdk- remove unnecessary file from sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

my sdk folder takes about 100GB of my disk space, I want to clean it up and only keep the necessary files, to do so , I've some question :

1- I'm using genymotion for my virtual device and I don't use android studio default emulator , do I need system images or I can remove them ? it get about 60GB of my disk usages

2- Do I need the all these sdk tools ? 
[image]

this is what I use in my gradle :

```
compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.persiandesigners.market"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

3-I've lots of thing installed in my sdk :
[image]

Do I need all of them ? 
please help me to tidy up my system

Comment: `Do I need all of them` you need only ones that you use as `targetSdkVersion`. You can delete all emulator system images.